# Flashing Previous Firmware to M1 Mini Without DFU Mode

Tags: thunderbolt, restore, mac-mini, firmware, apple-silicon

I just got a new M1 Mini in the mail (16gb RAM config).

Upon updating to Big Sur 11.2 , both of my thunderbolt ports were disabled.  I can't even get power from them to charge my other apple devices.  They were both working just fine prior to updating.

I spent an hour on the phone with a senior advisor from Apple and he had me run diagnostics on my system and filed a ticket with Apple and told me there's a 99% chance it's due to a bad firmware update with the new machines that was pushed with 11.2.

I was able to find the previous firmware version I was running in the form of an IPSW file.

I understand these are normally installed through DFU mode.  I cannot access DFU mode, as the thunderbolt ports don't work.....

Is there any way to install this IPSW file without the use of DFU mode? As much as I'd love to wait a week for Apple to get back to me on my case, I'd much prefer to have my thunderbolt ports working in the meantime....

For what it's worth: I can see both thunderbolt ports in System Information, they just never pick anything up when connecting devices.

Comment: Are you able to use Apple Configurator from a second Mac to revive the device? https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-configurator-2/revive-or-restore-a-mac-with-apple-silicon-apdd5f3c75ad/mac Or do you mean the thunderbolt ports do not work for something like that?

Comment: @negacao I tried doing this with my macbook pro.  The thunderbolt ports don't work for it....They don't work at all in general after the update.

Comment: Nuts, I was under the impression that it bypassed regular channels. I've not had luck so far finding any way to do what you're asking.